# Получить начало и конец разрыва в заданной последовательности натуральных чисел

Tags: sql

Дана таблица с цифрами, между которыми есть разрывы. Написать запрос, результатом которого будет 2 колонки. Первая колонка - это начало разрыва. Вторая - конец разрыва. Не использовать оконные функции (`Row_number`,`lag`,`lead`), циклы, `with`, временные таблицы.

Дано:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 6
>
> 8
>
> 12

Результат

> 2  |  6
>
> 6  |  8
>
> 8  |  11

Моё решение, но оно не является правильным:

```
CREATE TABLE ABD (
    [Dano][INT] NOT NULL
    )
    GO
INSERT INTO ABD 
VALUES  (1),
        (2),
        (6),
        (8),
        (11),
        (12)
GO

SELECT * FROM ABD
GO

SELECT*FROM ABD
WHERE Dano >=2 AND Dano <=11

SELECT * FROM ABD AS a1
INNER JOIN ABD AS a2 ON a1.Dano = a2.Dano 

WHERE a2.Dano IN (2,6,8,11)
```

Comment: Странно, не такой уж и плохой вопрос. Решить такое на sql сможет не каждый. Указаны исходные данные, желаемый результат, и попытки решения автором. И всё равно -4 голоса..

Comment: Anya, объясните тому кто задал эту задачу, что дана таблица с числами, а не с цифрами

Answer (score 2):

Нам нужна пара значений из одной и той же таблицы, поэтому мы будем *соединять* таблицу саму с собой.

При соединении нам надо указать *условие* соединения. К сожалению, мы не можем опираться на порядок строк, и не можем соединиться со следующей строкой.

Значит, придётся получать нужную пару в несколько шагов. Для начала отбросим все вторые значения, которые меньше первых.

```sql
   SELECT N1.n, N2.n
     FROM Naturals N1
     JOIN Naturals N2 ON N2.n > N1.n
```

Результат:

```
1   2
1   6
2   6
1   8
2   8
6   8
1   11
2   11
6   11
8   11
```

Если мы сгруппируем значения по `N1.n` и будем брать минимальное значение `N2.n`, то получим все пары подряд идущих чисел.

```sql
   SELECT N1.n, N2.n
     FROM Naturals N1
     JOIN Naturals N2 ON N2.n > N1.n
 GROUP BY N1.n
```

```
1   2
2   6
6   8
8   11
```

Не очень сложно, но и не очевидно. Я бы сказал, нужен навык решения *олимпиадных* задач по SQL.

Наконец, надо отобразить все пары, разница между которыми больше единицы. Вспоминаем, что сравнение мы осуществляем после группировки, поэтому используем `HAVING` вместо `WHERE`.

```sql
SELECT N1.n, MIN(N2.n)
  FROM Naturals N1
  JOIN Naturals N2 ON N2.n > N1.n
 GROUP BY N1.n
HAVING MIN(N2.n) > N1.n + 1
```

Результат:

```
2   6
6   8
8   11
```

Как раз то, что мы и хотели получить.